# Почему в слове "безжалостный" корень "жалост"

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Пришлось разбирать слово *жалостный* по составу, и я сделал ошибку при определении корня слова. Я взял слово *жалкий* и недолго думая определил *жал* корнем, а *ост* сделал суффиксом. Потом я узнал, что корень не *жал,* а *жалост,* а проверять надо не словом *жалкий,* а словом *жалость,* но у меня остался вопрос: почему для проверки не подошло слово *жалкий?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Словарь Тихонова на вашей стороне.

**безжалостный | без/жа'л/ост/н/ый**
http://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/tih-b.htm
Разбираться надо с преподавателем.

Я прокомментировать могу лишь следующим образом.
В языке встечаются ситуации, когда исторический корень "срастается" с суффиксом или приставкой и носители языка перестают вычленять исторический корень - это частный случай так называемого "морфемного переразложния".  В таких случаях в словарях могут наблюдаться разночтения, ориентированные на школу словари тогда для простоты дают современное членение. Возможно, ваш преподаватель (или автор пособия) так и воспринял это слово "жалость" - как нечленимую единицу, т. е. состоящую из одного корня.

Но словарь Тихонова - как раз "школьный" словарь. И коли уж там в этом слове нет подобных новаций, то можно быть уверенным, что мнение преподавателя в данном случае ошибочно.

Ну или вы не так его поняли...

Comment: Интересно, спасибо!

Comment: Ни в одном словаре не видела, чтоб выделялся корень -жалост-, может быть, речь идёт не о морфемном, а о морфемно-словообразовательном разборе и нужно было выстроить цепочку жалеть-жалкий-жалость-безжалостный. Жалост- производящая основа для слова безжалостный, а не корень. А что проверять-то? Гласный и так под ударением. А проверить правильный выбор корня можно, найдя наименьшую часть родственных слов - жаль.

Comment: @Людмила *Ни в одном словаре не видела, чтоб выделялся корень -жалост-,* - так и я не видел. ))) Насчет производящей основы - да, похоже на то. Но это все догадки...